# Wiring a ceiling light with conductive tape?

Tags: wiring, lighting

I'm wondering what's the downside to running conductive tape up the wall and across the ceiling to install a light fixture in the middle of my ceiling?

I feel like it's going to be less efficient, electricity wise, but I don't have a ceiling light right now and I saw a cafe in Berlin do this and I thought the copper up the wall effect was cool.

I'd probably just link up the end to a normal plug put that into a smart plug to control it from my phone.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that fixture you saw wasn't a low-voltage (say 12VDC) unit?

Comment: If the copper was exposed, it was certainly low voltage.

Comment: The copper tape was exposed yeah, but couldn't say for sure whether it was low-voltage. I would've thought it was 220V in Germany, but I was working and wasn't really paying close attention to the units. I should clarify that I have almost no experience with wiring lighting (lived in rental units my whole adult life).

Comment: Remembered the cafe; it's called betahaus in Berlin and the wiring I saw was like in this photo https://goo.gl/maps/CD4LU33wZKM2

Comment: The link did not work for me. But anything above ~32v would be required to be insulated, there are open conductor lighting fixtures bit all are low voltage AC or dc.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that's going to work (and all these are true there in Germany) is if

- the tape is fairly thick, because
- the circuit is low voltage
- the circuit has careful overcurrent protection on it
- the circuit has arc-fault protection on it (which isn't terribly hard on DC and static DC loads like resistor limited LED lighting)
- The copper tape is only installed where out of reach of poking fingers or damage from normal activity.

Have you checked **each** of the electrical sockets in your room?  It is common (especially in the US) for 1/2 of one receptacle (i.e. one socket of the two) to be swiched by the room's light switch.  This is done because it's about $30 cheaper in labor, x 3-4 rooms per house, x 2000 houses per development.  It is despicable and useless.  We usually go off to IKEA and get a simple $15 corner lamp to plug into that.

Another option is to use a product like Legrand Wiremold (tm) to run surface conduit from that switched receptacle up the side of the wall.  Then you can either extend it to a room light, or to around-the-edge cove lighting, or to that copper system you propose.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a condo where the upstairs bedroom had no fan. I ran a standard light cord from the outlet, up the wall, across the ceiling and into the fan. It worked well enough. Just screw the fixture to the ceiling itself, into a joist (drywall and anchors are not enough). Also, make sure the fan is a flush mount.

Comment: This would be a serious violation of electrical code in most jurisdictions. There are approved surface mount raceways that can accomplish the same thing safely and to code.

Comment: @bib I'm not claiming it was to code. If it were permanent, i would not suggest doing so. But for a temporary dwelling like an apartment it was sufficient

Comment: I certainly hope you at least attached the fan to a joist. Also being "temporary" does not make it ok, all human  structures are temporary.  I would buy "we built it for Burning Man" as temporary.

Comment: @Harper Good point about the fan mount. I added that to my answer. It was a flushmount attached to a joist with screws. As for temporary, the problem was I couldn't modify the wiring. As a DIY workaround, it sufficed pretty well